# Ethereum smart contract outside Ethereum network

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

Is it possible to use smart contract with cryptocurrency other than Ethereum?

Basically what i want is to use smart contract in place of traditional escrow method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! If I am understanding you correctly, you're referring to a token? With Ethereum, you are able to make your own [ERC-20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md) token via a smart contract. Although the title of the question seems to be referring to inter-blockchain communication. This is also possible. Here are a few examples of projects that incorporate inter-blockchain communication:

- [Aion](https://aion.network/)
- [Polkadot](https://polkadot.network/)
- [Cosmos](https://cosmos.network/)

Recently, Bancor and Aion teamed up to provide [inter-blockchain liquidity](https://www.cryptoninjas.net/2017/10/20/aion-bancor-partner-offer-inter-blockchain-liquidity/) which allows for "both data and value to transfer between chains".

[Amberdata.io](https://amberdata.io/) is working on implementing data analytics for inter-blockchain communication. For now, if you're interested in Aion you can explore their chain [here](https://aion-moldoveanu.amberdata.io/dashboards/infrastructure).

In regards to an escrow contract [here](https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/two-party-contracts/) is a tutorial on how one might build it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks alot. Just what I been looking for